# A sequence flow of requests in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a scenario when server needs to do authorization request before an actual request. so, one request are served by 2 different services.

Nginx's location has to be handled by Auth-Service, and if the response status is 200 OK, then the request should be forwarded to the Feature-Service. Otherwise, if the response status 401 then this status should be replied to front-end.

```
upstream auth_service {
    server localhost:8180;
}
upstream feature_service {
    server localhost:8080;
}
location /authAndDo {
    # suggest here
}
```

Comment: Are you asking of Nginx can route the same request to two different upstreams? Something similar to this has been asked a few times. Based on everything I've read, no, Nginx can't do that. Maybe there's a dedicated auth module that can do it, but I don't know of one. It sounds like your application needs to make two requests.

Comment: Yes. To different upstreams, but in a sequence.

Comment: That's exactly what `auth_request` is for http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html#auth_request

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for this purpose, http://nginx.org/r/auth_request exists through http://nginx.org/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html (not built by default).

It lets you put authentication, through a subrequest, into any location you want, effectively separating the authentication from the actual resource.